# FileSystemWatcher - sync changed files

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

Beginner programmer here....hope it makes sense :)

I have created a console app that I need to run in the background and watch a directory for any changes/rename events. I have used the FileWatcher class and have added the event handlers as so:

```
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
```

and defined the handlers then below like so:

```
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    //specify what is done when a file is changed, created or deleted
    Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
}
private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    //specify what is done when a file is renamed 
    Console.WriteLine("File {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
```

I would like to be able to add in some code that dumps any files that have changed/renamed into another local directory but I dont know where to start. At the minute the console is writing back the Fullpath to me but ideally I would like it to copy that into another folder

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string destination = Path.Combine(localDirectory, e.Name);` to create the destination path and `File.Copy(e.FullPath, destination);` actually copies the file.

Note that a process may still be writing to the file when you get the `Changed` event, so you may get an exception or copy half-processed data. Also you should think about what to do if the file already exists in your local directory (notice the `File.Copy(string, string, bool overwrite)` overload).

Also make sure you check if the changed item is a file and not a directory (for instance, by using `File.Exists(e.FullPath)`.